# Can I limit all site collections under a web application to use particular content source only?

Tags: result-source, content-source

We are using SP2013 on-premise (enterprise). A new web application is setup (`http://secure.myfirm.com/`). In Search service application I create a new content source **secure** to crawl `http://secure.myfirm.com/` only. I checked all other content source do not contain `http://secure.myfirm.com/`.

My question is how can I restrict all the site collection under  `http://secure.myfirm.com/` use only content source **secure**? I understand I can setup a new Result Source to query only at content source **secure** . However the site collection admin have permission to change result source the site collection use. I would like to block it, too. Is it possible?

Comment: Basically you want restrict the user, they can only get the result from Secure content Source as there site collection fall under the secure content source, right?

Comment: Yes. I want the search result bound within "secure" content source or bound within this web application.